# Удалить загруженные ресурсы по клику на кнопку

Tags: c#, unity3d

Загрузил ресурсы

```
var loadingRoomGameObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("QQQ"), new Vector3(0f, 700f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
```

по клику на кнопку мне нужно удалить это. Делаю так, но удаляется только со 2 нажатия, а нужно с первого. Что я делаю не так?

```
var DestroyRoom = GameObject.FindWithTag("Destroyy");
Destroy(DestroyRoom);
Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
```

Comment: может быть на сцене не один такой объект случайно?

Comment: Один) проверял. Я погуглил, вроде как UI блокирует удаление [https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000198623-Why-I-can-t-unload-Assets-that-were-referenced-by-scripts-which-were-also-referenced-by-UI-events-] только у меня все равно не выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var DestroingRoom = GameObject.FindWithTag("Destroyy");
    Destroy(DestroingRoom);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
```

Работает))